# How does RAM usage work with MPI_Bcast

Tags: mpi

For some background;
I am working on some code, trying to debug on a local system for code running on a cluster.  The code hung up on the cluster without exiting, making for a nice waste of cpu time (my fault for not monitoring it well).  Out of the 350 nodes, 68 got to the point of creating a folder with the rank number, but didnt do any of the computation (which takes 2 seconds) to create the file inside their own folders.

I am trying to test why it did.   The code works on my desktop with setting the nodes (rank) to 10.  I tried with 350, but that gave a pipe error, which seemed to be my local configuration.

Then I tried with 100 nodes.  This started to work, but I watched as the RAM increased, until my computer froze (64gb).

I assume this is because bcast is sending the data to 100 nodes all on the same system.  However, would this same issue arise on the cluster.  Does Bcast make multiple copies of the same data (since it is bcast it sends the same data to all nodes).

I read there is a tree system that bcast uses to get data to all nodes quickly.  When this is happening, does each node read from the same memory address or from a single copy stored on its own node.

Comment: Did you try to use `MPI_Bcast`with an empty message (just specify 0 elements in the call)?

Comment: @mort Bcast with 0 elements does not overload the RAM on my desktop, but I would like to know what it does when there are elements, so I can predict what will happen on the hpc.  Testing on the hpc is not the easiest and takes time/money since its a shared resource